# How to map through array that is within array? (reactjs)

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I have array of posts and inside of it I have userID which is object and inside of it I have followers that is array I need to loop through.

To simplify what I said, it looks like this:
[image]

What I need to do is display all posts (private or public) of my followers.

So the logic that I wrote is here:

```
    const availablePosts = postsArray?.map((post: PostInterface) => {
        const privatePosts = post.userID.followers.filter((follower: string) => {
            if (follower === userID) {
                console.log(post)
                return post
            }
        })
        return privatePosts
    })
```

`postArray` looks like in the image above, `userID` is current user id - the one who is logged in.

If I `console.log(post)` that is inside of the if statement I get whole post, and that is exactly what I need. That console looks like this:

[image]

And those are all posts of users that I'm following.

But if I console log `privatePosts` or `availablePosts` I'll get only array of ids, but I need whole post so I can display it in my app. And that looks like this: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

- using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) you iterate over array elements and try to create array of new objects. Here you iterate over all posts in `postsArray` and map them to arrays of followers (results of `filter`).
- using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) you create an array with items passing the implemented test. Here you testing for `follower === userID`. When values are equal you return `post`, but it just "informs the filter function" to return current `follower` in new array.

In the result, you get an array of followers arrays.

## Solution

Use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
const filtered = postsArray.reduce((acc, post) => {
  if (post.userID.followers && post.userID.followers.some(follower => follower === userId)) {
    acc.push(post);
  }

  return acc;
}, []);
```

`reduce` iterates over `postsArray` and checks if any of post followers passing the `follower === userID` test. If test succeed the post is pushed to `acc` array (`acc` stands for *accumulator*).

Full example:

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState(null);

  const filtered = postsArray.reduce((acc, post) => {
    if (post.userID.followers && post.userID.followers.some(follower => follower === userId)) {
      acc.push(post);
    }

    return acc;
  }, []);

  const posts = filtered.map(p => (
    <li key={p.id}>
      {p.visibility} - {p.id}
    </li>
  ));

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <label>Follower ID: </label>
        <input onChange={e => setUserId(e.target.value)} />
      </div>
      <div>{posts.length !== 0 ? <ul>{posts}</ul> : <span>No posts</span>}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

const postsArray = [
  {
    id: "post1",
    visibility: "Public",
    userID: {
      followers: ["1", "2", "3"]
    }
  },
  {
    id: "post2",
    visibility: "Private",
    userID: {
      followers: ["1", "2", "4"]
    }
  },
  {
    id: "post3",
    visibility: "Public",
    userID: {
      followers: ["2"]
    }
  },
  {
    id: "post4",
    visibility: "Private",
    userID: {
      followers: []
    }
  },
  {
    id: "post5",
    visibility: "Public",
    userID: {
      followers: null
    }
  },
  {
    id: "post6",
    visibility: "Private",
    userID: {}
  }
];

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```